# Android viewpager2 tab layout with FragmentStateAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-viewpager2

I am using ViewPager2 with Tab Layout. Here is my `MainFragment` code -

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding.viewPager.adapter = MyPagerAdapter(requireActivity())
    TabLayoutMediator(
        binding.tabLayout,  binding.viewPager
    ) { tab, position ->
        binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true)
        when (position) {
            0 -> tab.text = “Tab A”
            1 -> tab.text = “Tab B”      
        }
    }.attach()
}


private class MyPagerAdapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {
    private val items = 2
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment = when (position) {
        0 -> FragmentA()
        1 -> FragmentB()
        else -> FragmentA()
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions here -

1. `override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment` creates new instance of child fragments every time the `MainFragment` view is created. Is there no way to re-use an already existing instance of child fragment?
2. In my Navigation graph, I have the `MainFragment` and its children `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`. Why cant I use the Navigation action to open children from its parent? If yes, `override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment` needs a Fragment to be returned and `findNavController().navigate()` does not return anything. How do I do this?

Comment: so you want to open child fragment such as FRAGMENT A and FRAGMENT B staying in parent fragment as MAIN FRAGMENT using navigation.

Answer (score -1):

> you can follow this sample code, may this will help you

class TvShowsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.tvshows_fragment) {

```
private var _binding: TvshowsFragmentBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    _binding = TvshowsFragmentBinding.bind(view)

    setUpViewPager()
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

private fun setUpViewPager() {
    val viewPager = binding.vpTvShows
    val tab = binding.tlTvShows
    val adapterTv = TvAdapter(this)
    viewPager.adapter = adapterTv

    TabLayoutMediator(tab, viewPager) { tabText, position ->
        tabText.text = when (position) {
            0 -> getString(R.string.title_tvAiringToday)
            1 -> getString(R.string.title_tvOnTheAir)
            2 -> getString(R.string.title_popular)
            3 -> getString(R.string.title_topRated)
            else -> getString(R.string.title_tvAiringToday)

        }
    }.attach()

}

private inner class TvAdapter(fm: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 4

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> TvAiringTodayFragment()
            1 -> TvOnTheAirFragment()
            2 -> TvPopularFragment()
            3 -> TvTopRatedFragment()
            else -> TvAiringTodayFragment()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. I also have the same implementation